# TypeError: 'LazyCorpusLoader' object is not iterable in TfidfVectorizer

Tags: python, scikit-learn, tf-idf

I have seen a separate thread on this issue. But my error is generating from using different step. So the duplicate post
I'm using Python 3.x. I need to do text clustering using text contains compound noun. I used Splitter in charsplit to split the compound noun. I'm using following code to do this

```
from charsplit import Splitter
text=list()
length=1
length=len(texts)
splitted=[]
unSplitted=[]

for i in range(length):
    try:
        splitter = Splitter()
        z=splitter.split_compound(texts[i])
       # print("Text : "+texts[i])
        
        split=pd.DataFrame(z)
        #Print("splited text : ",z)
        #print("i=" +str(i)+"Text : "+texts[i])
        
        #split.head()
        splitted=split[split[0]==split[0].max()][1].to_string()+" "+split[split[0]==split[0].max()][2].to_string()
        #print("Splitted= "+splitted)
        #mylist=[split[split[0]==split[0].max()].iloc[:,[1,2]]]    
        #splitted.append(mylist)
        splitted.append(splitted)
    except:
        unSplitted.append(texts[i])
```

Sample of my splitted list looks like

```
[0    waterflow Plus-/Minus- on right channel 0    interface',
 '0    flow  , Automatic valve Start/Stop    left',
 '0    flow 0    , Automatic valve Start/Stop ...',
```

I want to do text clustering using this splitted text. So I'm using -TfidfVectorizer & wrote following code

```
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(
    stop_words=stopwords,
)

X = vectorizer.fit_transform(splitted_german)
```

But it's throwing error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_411/935444557.py in <module>
      4 )
      5 
----> 6 X = vectorizer.fit_transform(splitted_german)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py in fit_transform(self, raw_documents, y)
   2075         """
   2076         self._check_params()
-> 2077         X = super().fit_transform(raw_documents)
   2078         self._tfidf.fit(X)
   2079         # X is already a transformed view of raw_documents so

/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py in fit_transform(self, raw_documents, y)
   1328                     break
   1329 
-> 1330         vocabulary, X = self._count_vocab(raw_documents, self.fixed_vocabulary_)
   1331 
   1332         if self.binary:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py in _count_vocab(self, raw_documents, fixed_vocab)
   1191             vocabulary.default_factory = vocabulary.__len__
   1192 
-> 1193         analyze = self.build_analyzer()
   1194         j_indices = []
   1195         indptr = []

/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py in build_analyzer(self)
    444 
    445         elif self.analyzer == "word":
--> 446             stop_words = self.get_stop_words()
    447             tokenize = self.build_tokenizer()
    448             self._check_stop_words_consistency(stop_words, preprocess, tokenize)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py in get_stop_words(self)
    366                 A list of stop words.
    367         """
--> 368         return _check_stop_list(self.stop_words)
    369 
    370     def _check_stop_words_consistency(self, stop_words, preprocess, tokenize):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py in _check_stop_list(stop)
    190         return None
    191     else:  # assume it's a collection
--> 192         return frozenset(stop)
    193 
    194 

TypeError: 'LazyCorpusLoader' object is not iterable
```

Can you guide me to resolve the issue?

Comment: How do you create `stopwords`?

Comment: I have taken language specific stopwords and generated a stopwords as a list stopwords=[]

Comment: Did you use `nltk` anywhere?

Comment: No, I didn't use nltk

Comment: Ok because `LazyCorpusLoader` is from nltk. Could you write here the output of `print(stopwords)` just before the line where you create `vectorizer` please?